# Index out of Range with array of structs in Go

Tags: go

I am new to Go so hopefully I'm making myself clear with this issue I'm having.  My problem is that I am trying to iterate over an array of structs but I keep running into an `index out of range` issue.  For the purposes of this problem, I have already verified that my array is not empty but that it in fact does contain at least one `Services` struct and `file_content` is the string that contains my valid `JSON`

Here is the snippet of code that represents the problem I'm having:

```
type service_config struct {
    Services []struct {
        Name    string
        Command string
        Request map[string]interface{}
    }
}

var ServiceConf = service_config{}

err_json := json.Unmarshal(file_content, &ServiceConf)

for _, s := range ServiceConf.Services {
  log.Println(s)
}
```

So every time I run my code I get:

`2014/03/14 18:19:53 http: panic serving [::1]:65448: runtime error: index out of range`

```
{
  "services" : [
    {
      "name": "translation",
      "command": "to german",
      "request": {
        "key": "XXX",
        "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you're interested in the complete source file:

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

type SlackResponse struct {
    token        string
    team_id      string
    channel_id   string
    channel_name string
    timestamp    string
    user_id      string
    user_name    string
    text         string
}

type service_config struct {
    Services []struct {
        Name    string
        Command string
        Request map[string]interface{}
    }
}

var ServiceConf = service_config{}

func main() {

    content, err_read := ioutil.ReadFile("config.ini")

    if err_read != nil {
        log.Println("Could not read config")
        return
    }

    log.Println(string(content))

    err_json := json.Unmarshal(content, &ServiceConf)

    if err_json != nil {
        log.Println(err_json)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    slack_response := SlackResponse{
        r.FormValue("token"),
        r.FormValue("team_id"),
        r.FormValue("channel_id"),
        r.FormValue("channel_name"),
        r.FormValue("timestamp"),
        r.FormValue("user_id"),
        r.FormValue("user_name"),
        r.FormValue("text"),
    }

    // log.Println(ServiceConf.Services[0].Request["key"])

    // loop through services to find command phrases
    for _, s := range ServiceConf.Services {
        log.Println(s)
    }

    if slack_response.user_name == "slackbot" {
        return
    }

    // fmt.Fprintf(w, "{ \"text\": \"Master %s!  You said: '%s'\" }", slack_response.user_name, slack_response.text)

    content, err := getContent("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=&source=en&target=de&q=" + url.QueryEscape(slack_response.text))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "{ \"text\": \"Huh?!\" }")
    } else {

        type trans struct {
            Data struct {
                Translations []struct {
                    TranslatedText string `json:"translatedText"`
                } `json:"translations"`
            } `json:"data"`
        }

        f := trans{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(content, &f)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "{ \"text\": \"Translated to German you said: '%s'\" }", f.Data.Translations[0].TranslatedText)
    }
}

// array of bytes if retrieved successfully.
func getContent(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    // Build the request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Send the request via a client
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Defer the closing of the body
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // Read the content into a byte array
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // At this point we're done - simply return the bytes
    return body, nil
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
2014/03/21 23:21:29 http: panic serving [::1]:59508: runtime error: index out of range
goroutine 3 [running]:
net/http.func·009()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1093 +0xae
runtime.panic(0x215f80, 0x4b6537)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x106
main.handler(0x5a85e8, 0xc21000f6e0, 0xc210037dd0)
    /Users/et/src/go/src/github.com/etdebruin/gojacques/main.go:100 +0x81b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x2cbc60, 0x5a85e8, 0xc21000f6e0, 0xc210037dd0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1220 +0x40
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc21001e5d0, 0x5a85e8, 0xc21000f6e0, 0xc210037dd0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1496 +0x163
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc21001f500, 0x5a85e8, 0xc21000f6e0, 0xc210037dd0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1597 +0x16e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc210058300)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1167 +0x7b7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1644 +0x28b
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the json you are using?  I mocked this up and it appears to work fine, so I'm wondering if you have a data problem?  Does it error out? http://play.golang.org/p/IQUdCq9zNT

Comment: Thanks for checking this out.  I updated the Question with the JSON sample.

Comment: Post the code which actually produces the error and you'll get more help!

Comment: So this appears to work fine (http://play.golang.org/p/-uOnU3NMhF).  I'm guessing the code is different in some way than what you are showing above?

Comment: Also, you are getting an http error, nothing in the code above could throw that type of error, so I suspect this code really isn't your problem.

Comment: I posted the full source code.  I was thinking the issue could be with my understanding of scoping, pointers, etc.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your config.ini as well so I can run this completely locally to debug it?

Comment: @CoryLaNou The config.ini contains the JSON snippet I posted in the question.

Comment: @CoryLaNou I added the full stack trace.

Comment: So what code is at line 100 in `gojacques/main.go` ?

Comment: I found the problem.  It was a red herring.  The problem is I was not getting a result from my URL get.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from this line

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "{ \"text\": \"Translated to German you said: '%s'\" }",
    f.Data.Translations[0].TranslatedText)
```

So you didn't get any `Translations` back - that array is empty.

You might want to check `resp.Status` to see if an error was returned.  This isn't returned as an error - you need to check it yourself.

Comment: I'll definitely check resp.Status but that's a different error because you need to query the translation service with a valid key, which I did not include in my JSON snippet.  The error I keep getting is the 'index out of range' error.

Comment: @Etienne You should get a panic, and the panic should show you *exactly* which line the problem is. I suspect it will be the one above, but if not add it to your question.

Comment: Yes, the panic tells me `index out of range` and I posted the full panic text in my question.

Comment: @Etienne there should be about 20 lines of stack trace which goes with it.  In the first few lines you'll see exactly where the panic was produced.  This will come out to standard error.

Comment: Added the full stack trace.